# Paragraphs formatting slow in VSTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vsto

I am using VSTO to get some paragraphs and save their formatting in a List.The code is working fine but the problem is that this function is taking almost 50% of the execution time of my program.
It is also known that the loop is making performance slow.
I want to know that how can I optimize the time of this function.Any alternative to list or any other thing?

```
public static void GetFormattedParas(Range content, Driver currentDriver)
{
    // TODO add check for tables row end "\r\a" words to ignore them for query

    Paragraphs paras = content.Paragraphs;
    List<Paragraph> paraList = paras.Cast<Paragraph>().ToList();
    List<Range> Ranges = new List<Range>();
    if (paraList != null)
    {
        paraList.RemoveAll(range => range.Range.Text == null);

        paraList.RemoveAll(range => range.Range.Text.Equals("\r\a") && range.Range.Tables.Count != 0 && range.Range.Rows[1].Range.End == range.Range.End);

        for (int i = 0, ParaCount = paraList.Count; i < ParaCount; i++)
        {
            Range range = paraList[i].Range;
            if (range.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight
                    || range.HighlightColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight
                    || range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight)
            {
                Ranges.Add(paraList[i].Range);
            }
        }


        //Ranges = (from range in paraList
        //          where range.Range.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight
        //          || range.Range.HighlightColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight
        //          || range.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex != WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight
        //          select range.Range).OrderBy(o => o.Start).ToList();

        if (Ranges != null)
        {
            Ranges = Ranges.OrderBy(o => o.Start).ToList();
            if (Ranges.Count > 0)
            {
                //if (Ranges.Count == 1)
                //{
                //    currentDriver.formattedParas.Add(content);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                currentDriver.formattedParas.AddRange(Ranges);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this function is taking almost 50% of the execution time of my program.` Which particular line / part of the code is slow, according to your profiling?

Comment: The one having condition in loop @mjwills

Comment: What is the value of `ParaCount`?

Comment: its is about 200-300 @mjwills

Comment: Try ``OpenXML``. As I know ``Office.Interup`` and ``OOXML`` are not compatible at runtime. You could close the doc from word (if in Word UI), load in OOXML proceed (all tasks over paragraphs), save, open back the doc (if closed in Word UI). ``OOXML`` is 10x faster, now it depend on how you want to eat your final list

Comment: Interop and OOXML are in fact [compatible at runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191178%28v=office.14%29.aspx).